# Implement interface methods that do nothing

Tags: java, design-patterns, adapter

Lets say I have this interface and class:

```
interface IListener
{
   void f();
   void g();
   void h();
}

class Adapter implements IListener
{
   void f() {}
   void g() {}
   void h() {}
}
```

What is the point of implementing thoose interface methods if they do nothing ?

Question taken from [Design Patterns Java Workbook](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201743973).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The aim is to makes the implementation of the interface easier if you don't need all the methods. You can extend the adapter and override only the methods you want to. These classes only exist for convenience.

For example, in Swing, when implementing a [`MouseListener`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseListener.html), you might not want to treat all the mouse events. In this case, you can extends [`MouseAdapter`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseAdapter.html) and treat only the events you are interested in.

Please note that the `Adapter` class usually implements the interface as well.

Comment: If you make an interface public, you should expect people to implement it directly. At least some of them will do it. If you want to be sure *not* to break any implementation, don't create the interface. Only the empty methods.

Comment: Please note that the Adapter class usually implements the interface as well..... If not always.

Answer (score 2):

In the example you posted it is useless, however if you make adapter to implement IListener (`class Adapter implements IListener`), it becomes a bit more usefull as you can than instantiate an Adaptor object like `new Adapter()`;

Otherwise Adapter would remain an abstract class which cant be instantiated nor its children until all the methods defined in the interface have a proper implementation. An empty implementation being also a proper implementation.

Comment: I have made the corections, it was a typo. Sorry.

Comment: Good thing you fixed it this early now you only have to apologize to 2 :-)